# Sibling vs Parent-Child relative positioning and event bubbling

Tags: html, css, angular, css-position

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.foo{
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%; /*This cannot be changed.*/
  top: 25%; /*This cannot be changed.*/
  width: 50px; /*This cannot be changed.*/
  height: 50px; /*This cannot be changed.*/
}

.fooBorder{
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 22%; /*This cannot be changed.*/
  top: 22%; /*This cannot be changed.*/
  width: 50px; /*This cannot be changed.*/
  height: 50px; /*This cannot be changed.*/
}
```

```html
<h3>Situation 1</h3>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="foo" onClick="alert('foo')"></div>
  <div class="fooBorder" onClick="alert('fooBorder')"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h3>Situation 2</h3>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fooBorder" onClick="alert('fooBorder')">
      <div class="foo" onClick="alert('foo')"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a dilemma, and can't consolidate two problems. I'd like the best of both worlds but it's impossible.

In **situation 1** both foo and fooBorder position relative to the parent. This is how I want to position my elements. But when you click only fooBorder gets a click event. However I must have a click event on both elements.

In **situation 2** foo is a child of fooBorder, this is how I want to structure my html but I want the positioning from situation 1. However now the click events work correctly on both foo and fooBorder.

I'd compromise and choose situation 1 for the positioning if I could just get the events to work. In reality the situation is more complex, I simplified it. It's actually an angular application, if that could help.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you can use (2) and rectify the position using translate, no?

Comment: @Temani Afif no, it's a lot of elements and I don't want to manually tweak them all.